# Google Pay - CRYPTOGRAM_3DS

Tags: javascript, google-pay

While using Google Pay API, and with the "allowedCardAuthMethods" set to "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS" only, "isReadyToPay" promise outcome is always "false".

Knowing that i am trying from my Android device where i have a card enrolled.

While when using ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"] the "isReadyToPay" is "true".

Comment: Are you able to share a link to your implementation so I can try myself? Also, when you say "where I have a card enrolled" you mean you enrolled the card in the Google Wallet App. Correct?